# Better to encode ADD EAX,4 as r/m32 imm32 or r32 imm8? x86 assembly

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, x86

Given the instruction:

```
ADD EAX, 4
```

in x86 assembly P2+, would it be better to encode this as `ADD EAX, imm32` (op code 05) or `ADD r/m32, imm8` (op code 83 /0), if the goal is execution speed and code size is irrelevant?

Note that EAX is a pointer in this case so `ADD AL, imm8` is not viable.

Option 2 (op code 83 /0) will lead to a smaller code size, but from my limited understanding it may not pipeline as well as option 1, even though it is shorter.

Comment: You might also consider `lea eax, [eax+4]` depending on the context.

Comment: Or add constant offset when dereferencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not optimising for one specific CPU (e.g. "Intel Pentium II, model 2" and not just "P2+"), just guess. Regardless of how you guess, some CPUs might be faster and some might be slower (but I'd expect that for most CPUs it won't make any difference at all).

If you are optimising for one specific CPU, just guess. The alternative is to profile it under the exact conditions you plan to use it, and then realise that you want to change the code 2 days later and that you wasted 8 hours messing about with profiling for nothing.

Finally; if you're writing a code optimiser (e.g. as part of a compiler back-end or an optimising assembler), then just guess - you've got far more important things to worry about than this. The alternative is to get about 50 different computers and profile many different sequences of instructions on all of them; and use the results to create rules for many different cases.

Comment: If fact, guess for the shorter instruction. Modern x86s execute "simple" instructions (both of these are that) generally quite fast.  If you use shorter instructions, your loops will tend be in fewer cache lines and that will probably have a noticeable effect.   While we're at this, A. Webb in another comment remarked that LEA instructions are also a good choice.  The x86 designers actually go through a lot of trouble to optimize address arithmetic and consequently LEA instructions usually have special paths.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the short form 83 /0.  Code density will improve, which means performance and power consumption have a modest chance to improve on many processors.  There is no upside to encoding fat immediate values.

Instruction cache size on a modern x86 processor is at least 32KB, which means modest code density improvements **won't really improve caching**.  See the paper "The Impact of Code Density on Instruction Cache Performance" by [Steenkiste](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~prs/papers.html).  Sorry, I can't seem to find a free link for that one.

The real potential win is for dense code executing in a tight loop.  If the loop is tight enough, modern processors can take shortcuts in which they fetch and decode the instructions only once, then execute the small loop from internal buffering inside the pipeline itself.  Even if loop performance is limited due to data hazards or whatever, these tricks still reduce power consumption.

Comment: If you're writing a compiler, code-density improvements add up over large amounts of code.  But yes, shorter is generally better, generally allowing better packing into the uop cache and other front-end benefits.